# Tibco business works

Tags: java, tibco, tibco-ems, businessworks

I am getting the following error in Tibco business works designer. Please assist.

```
/temp/javaCode/ProcessDefinitionJavaCode.java:23: cannot resolve symbol
symbol  : class PasswordProtection 
location: class java.security.KeyStore
    KeyStore.PasswordProtection password;
            ^

/temp/javaCode/ProcessDefinitionJavaCode.java:31: cannot resolve symbol
symbol  : class PasswordProtection 
location: class java.security.KeyStore
        password = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection("changeme".toCharArray());
                               ^

2 errors
```

Comment: May be you are forgetting to import a package name.

Comment: @Searock it is able to compile when i remove the KeyStore in tibco business works. it also works when i compile it manually in msdos but it does not compile in tibco business work.

Comment: Are you using the same Java version in both compilations? KeyStore.PasswordProtection needs Java 5.

Answer (score 1):

I have never trusted compiling code inside Designer, so I always generate a jar and then include this in the project and call the method via a Java process.

The benefit of this is you can then build a JUnit test suite and make sure the java code works properly before involving TIBCO. Just be sure to follow all the rules when using Java.

Answer (score -1):

You need'nt to write class name and main method just start writing your code. TIBCO BW Java paletted doesn't need to write a class name and main method name,by default it is there.

Answer (score -2):

Class KeyStore.PasswordProtection since java 1.5
Check your Java version in CMD:

```
java -version
```